# Rx Show Loading(Progress Bar or something like that) If Web request takes too long

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Im Developing Xamarin.Ios little dictionary app , it sends a GET request to server and it returns the value by key(word) , text input is on SearchBar and i have observable on its TextChanged Event, the good thing is that i managed to send request by observables ,but i want to show LoadingView if Request takes more than 1 or 2 sec... I tried Buffer() but it did not work, so here is the code thanks!!

```
var dataStream = Observable.FromEventPattern<UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs>(ev => searchBar.TextChanged += ev,
                        ev => searchBar.TextChanged -= ev)
    .Select(o => o.EventArgs.SearchText)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Select(t =>
    {
        #if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        #endif
        var instance = TranslateWebClient.Instance;//this is WebClient From where Get Request is made
        var data = instance.GetWordAsync(t);
        return data.ToObservable().ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
    })
.Switch();

dataStream.Subscribe(o =>
{
    if (o == null || o.Count() == 0)
    {
        wordsTableView.DataSource = null;
        wordsTableView.ReloadData();
        return;
    }
    _words = o;
    initDataToUI();
}, ex =>
{
    if (ex is WebClient.NoInternetException)
    {
        //handle exception
    }
});
```

Comment: either use Async versions of calls or wrap it into "await Task.Run"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think something like this will work. Add this enum, or use something similar if available:

```
enum LoadState
{
    InitialState,
    RequestSent,
    ResponseLate,
    ResponseReceived
}
```

...then change your `dataStream` declaration to the following:

```
var requestStream = Observable.FromEventPattern<UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs>(ev => searchBar.TextChanged += ev,
                        ev => searchBar.TextChanged -= ev)
    .Select(o => o.EventArgs.SearchText)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Select(t =>
    {
#if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine(t);
#endif
    var instance = TranslateWebClient.Instance;//this is WebClient From where Get Request is made
    var data = instance.GetWordAsync(t);
        return data.ToObservable().ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
    })
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();

requestStream
    .SelectMany(o => Observable.Merge(
        Observable.Return(LoadState.RequestSent),
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => LoadState.ResponseLate),
        o.Select(_ => LoadState.ResponseReceived))
    )
    .Scan(LoadState.InitialState, 
        (previousState, newState) => previousState == LoadState.ResponseReceived && newState == LoadState.ResponseLate 
            ? LoadState.ResponseReceived 
            : newState
    )
    .Subscribe(state =>
    {
        if(state == LoadState.ResponseLate)
            ; //enable loading UI
        else
            ; //disable loading UI
    });

var dataStream = requestStream.Switch();
```

**Explanation**: `requestStream` emits an observable representing each web request. The new subscription I think matches the business rules you have in mind: Display a waiting UI when the delay has gotten to 1 second or more, then cancel the waiting UI if they make a new request or the response is received.

Comment: Nice. I was writing a very similar solution, but struggled with handling the state with `Scan`

Comment: you need to add ObserveOn after scan  ,Thanks a lot! It works you saved my day :)